# Cross validation and logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I am analyzing a dataset from kaggle and want to apply a logistic regression model to predict something. This is the data: https://www.kaggle.com/code/mohamedadelhosny/stroke-prediction-data-analysis-challenge/data

I split the data into train and test, and want to use cross validation to inssure highest accuracy possible. I did some pre-processing and used the dummy function over catigorical features, got to a certain point in the code, and and I don't know how to proceed. I cant figure out how to use the results of the cross validation, it's not so straight forward.

This is what I got so far:

```
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = data_Enco.iloc[:, data_Enco.columns != 'stroke'].values  # features
Y = data_Enco.iloc[:, 6]  # labels

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20) 

scaler = MinMaxScaler() 
scaled_X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train) 
scaled_X_test = scaler.transform(X_test) 

# prepare the cross-validation procedure

cv = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
logisticModel = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')

# evaluate model
scores = cross_val_score(logisticModel, scaled_X_train, Y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv)

print('average score = ', np.mean(scores))
print('std of scores = ', np.std(scores))

average score =  0.7483538453549359
std of scores =  0.0190400919099899
```

So far so good.. I got the results of the model for each 10 splits. But now what? how do I build a confusion matrix? how do I calculate the recall, precesion..? I have the right code without performing cross validation, I just dont know how to adapt it.. how do I use the `scores` of the `cross_val_score` function ?

```
logisticModel = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced')
logisticModel.fit(scaled_X_train, Y_train) # Train the model
predictions_log = logisticModel.predict(scaled_X_test)

## Scoring the model
logisticModel.score(scaled_X_test,Y_test)

## Confusion Matrix

Y_pred = logisticModel.predict(scaled_X_test)
real_data = Y_test

print('Observe the difference between the real data and the data predicted by the knn classifier:\n')
print('Predictions: ',Y_pred,'\n\n')
print('Real Data:m', real_data,'\n')

cmtx = pd.DataFrame(
    confusion_matrix(real_data, Y_pred, labels=[0, 1]), 
    index = ['real 0: ', 'real 1:'], columns = ['pred 0:', 'pred 1:']
)
print(cmtx)

print('Accuracy score is: ',accuracy_score(real_data, Y_pred))
print('Precision score is: ',precision_score(real_data, Y_pred))
print('Recall Score is: ',recall_score(real_data, Y_pred))
print('F1 Score is: ',f1_score(real_data, Y_pred))
```

Comment: What do you mean with adapt the scores?
You got the scores from the train dataset, so you have the performance of this data and then you evaluate the test set using confusion matrix and the others metrics.
What exactly you want to do here?

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos How do I choose the best model, out of the cross validation models?

Answer (score 0):

The performance of a model on the training dataset is not a good estimator of the performance on new data because of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Cross-validation is used to obtain an estimation of the performance of your model on new data, i.e. without overfitting. And you correctly applied it to compute the mean and variance of the accuracy of your model. This should be a much better approximation of the accuracy on your test dataset than the accuracy on your training dataset. And that is it.

However, cross-validation is usually used to do ***model selection***. Say you have two logistic regression models that use different sets of independent variables. E.g., one is using only age and gender while the other one is using age, gender, and bmi. Or you want to compare logistic regression with an SVM model.

I.e. you have ***several*** possible models and you want to decide which one is best. Of course, you cannot just compare the training dataset accuracies of all the models because those are spoiled by overfitting. And if you use the performance on the test dataset for choosing the best model, the test dataset becomes part of the training, you will have [leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning)), and thus the performance on the test dataset cannot be used anymore for a final, untainted performance measure. That is why cross-validation is used which creates those splits that contain different versions of validation sets.

So the idea is to

- apply cross-validation to each of your candidate models,
- use the scores of those cross-validations to choose the best model,
- retrain that best model on the *complete* training dataset to get a final version of your best model, and
- to finally apply this final version to the test dataset to obtain some untainted evaluation.

---

But note, that those three steps are for *model selection*. However, you have only a *single* model, the logistic regression, so there is nothing to select from. If you fit your model, let's call it m(p) where p denotes the parameters, to e.g. five folds of CV, you get five different fitted versions m(p1), m(p2), ..., m(p5) of the *same* model.

So if you have only one model, you fit it to the complete training dataset, maybe use CV to have an additional estimate for the performance on new data, but that's it. But you have already done this. There is no "selection of best model", that is only for if you have several models as described above, like e.g. logistic regression and SVM.

Comment: Yes, how do I do the last three steps? that's what I wanted, I got the scores, now I need to choose the best model and train on the complete training set, and then test set. How do I do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I see.. so it's just some type of evaluation in cases like this.
Ok, thank you very much.